Is pyspark ALS reproduce deterministic results and factors beyond using seeding?
I've been using PySpark's Alternating Least Squares (ALS) algorithm for a recommendation system, and I've set the seed for initializing the latent factors to ensure reproducibility. However, I still observe different latent factors and predictions across multiple runs, even with the same seed set.
Despite setting seed=42, the results vary each time I run the script. I'm aware that distributed computing can introduce some level of non-determinism, but I would like to understand:

Is PySpark ALS expected to be fully deterministic beyond the initial random seed?
What factors might cause the variation in results, even with the same seed?
Are there any best practices or additional configurations to ensure more consistent results in a distributed setting?
Is there any case in which Databricks DBR version can affect the ALS reproducibility?

